# LINK error in visual studio with boost date_time library

Tags: boost, visual-studio-2013

I built date_time library only and set up property page like this:

```
linker > input > additional dependencies:
libboost_date_time-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib boost_date_time-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)

VC++ directories > library directories:
C:\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib;$(LibraryPath)

VC++ directories > include directories:
C:\boost_1_55_0;$(IncludePath)
```

when runing build I got following error:

> 1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file
>   'boost_date_time-vc120-mt-gd-1_55.lib.obj'

linker can't find the *.obj file, I can't find it either, where do need to look for *.obj file and what to do once I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't specify additional dependencies. Boost will auto link libraries using `#pragma comment(lib, "<lib name>")` when you include their headers. Try removing those explicit dependencies and rebuild.